# How to set a variable to an if condition

Tags: ruby

I have this condition:

```rb
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

arr1.each do |num|
  if num == arr1.last
    print "#{num}\n"
    exit
  else
    print "#{num} x "
  end
end
```

and I have to print this like a variable, maybe called num_printer, so that if I write

```rb
  puts num_printer
```

it should print this

```rb
  1 x 2 x 3 x 4
```

But I don't know how to do this.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see `num_printer` method defined...

Comment: "_maybe_ called num_printer" @orde...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to insert something (' x ' in your case) between the elements and output the result. Use [join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

```rb
puts arr1.join(' x ')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are simpler ways to accomplish this as Maxim points out in their answer, but to answer your question, you could accomplish this by initializing an empty string variable and then in your `each` block appending text to the variable instead of printing it:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
nums_str = ""

arr1.each do |num|
  if num == arr1.last
    nums_str << num.to_s
  else
    nums_str << "#{num} x "
  end
end

puts nums_str
# => 1 x 2 x 3 x 4
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/ArcticDeficientArchitecture

Comment: `arr1.last` is suspicious - what if there is another 4 before the last?

Comment: @steenslag I agree, but that's a question for OP.